# Windows 7 often stops pinging with Linux router

Tags: windows-7, linux

I am facing a problem in my network environment. I have windows XP, Windows 7 and windows 8 clients. DNS server is on Microsoft server 2008 R2. DHCP and proxy server is on Ubuntu 8.0.4. Windows XP users have no issue at all but Win 7 & 8 clients often having problem request time out with Linux gateway.